# PHP autoformat in Dreamweaver

Tags: php, dreamweaver, auto-indent, autoformatting

I've googled around, but haven't found satisfactory answers to this question, or any recent ones.  I'm hoping some new developments have occurred since some of the older types of this question.  I would really like to be able to autoformat PHP in Dreamweaver.  By auto-format I mean hit "control-f" or a similar key combo and have all of my brackets go to the correct indentation level, as well as all of the code within those brackets.  I'd prefer not to use an extension, but if you know a good one for Dreamweaver, you can mention it too.

I did hear once this is possible to set up manually by going to Edit->Preferences->Code Format, but from there I am once more stuck, even though I see there is some mention of PHP within the "Advanced Formatting"->"Tag Libraries", but I don't understand what can be done from that point.

I appreciate any insight!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use NetBeans (just a thought). :)

Comment: Which version of DW are you using?

Comment: I just bought a monthly subscription to dreamweaver cc